# Defining a block in a switch statement results in a compiler error

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following switch statement:

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self fooWithCompletion:^{
            [weakSelf finishEditing];
        }];
        break;
    case 1: // Error here
        [self barWithCompletion:^{
            [weakSelf finishEditing];
        }];
        break;    
    default:
        break;
}
```

It causes the compiler error

**`Cannot jump from switch statement to this case label`**

on the line `case 1:`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The block definition creates a new scope which seems to interfere with the compiler's ability to correctly interpret the switch statement.

Adding scope delimiters for each case label resolves the error. I think this is because the block's scope is now unambiguously a child of the case scope.

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
    {
        [self updateUserDataWithCompletion:^{
            [weakSelf finishEditing];
        }];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        [self updateOtherDataWithCompletion:^{
            [weakSelf finishEditing];
        }];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

There's a [bug open with LLVM](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25294) for a similar issue.

Comment: Strange... I was scratching my head. BTW adding these brackets only on case which is before the case in which error is shown also resolve the problem.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your comment. Missed this in my testing because I applied braces throughout for consistency

Comment: Even array element access within a case triggers this bug.